# Using search operators with Surfraw

Tags: search, command-line, operators

I just discovered Surfraw and I'm very impressed with it so far.  There's only one little thing about it that's frustrating me.  That thing is that I cannot figure out how to use search operators with it.  For example, I want to do a Google search via Surfraw and I want to only have search results that have a certain word or words omitted from them.  When doing a Google search from a regular browser, I use a '-' to accomplish that. I tried doing that with Surfraw and I get an error message. I even try putting single and double quotes around that search operator and I still get an error message.  Just what am I doing wrong, if anything?

Comment: And yes, I tried 'sr google -local-help' but couldn't find anything doing that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If additional clarification is needed, take for example if I was using Google in a regular browser (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, et al.) and I did a search for websites pertaining to travel but, say, I wanted Google to exclude all results that mention Canada, I would type in, 'travel -canada.'. Well, if I try doing a search like that using Surfraw, I get an error message because of the '-canada' added onto the search query.  Is there a way to let Surfraw know that is part of the search query?